# Имя кнопки и его использование в POST

Tags: php

Имеется кнопка в форме. Атрибут name она получает из переменной:

```
<input type="submit" name="<?php echo $create ?> value="Создать">
```

как правильно обратиться к этой кнопке через POST?

```
if(isset($_POST[name]))
```

Comment: Форма завернута в foreache. Соответственно у каждой выведенной строки должна быть своя кнопка с id этой строки. И при нажатии кнопки в одной из строк должен отрабатываться запрос касающийся только этой строки.

Answer (score 0):

$_POST[name] будет содержать в себе строку "Создать" на данный момент (атрибут value). Чуть-чуть раскройте пожалуйста, что Вам нужно сделать?

Если Вы хотите обработать результаты формы, то все отправленные поля будут находиться в массиве $_POST при клике на эту кнопку.

Если же Вам необходимо что то сделать с кнопкой без отправки формы, то это JS. Что-то вроде

```
let button = document.querySelector('form input[type=submit]')
```

Если нет ID у поля.